# Multiple Dynamic Databases in Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to set up a Flask based CRUD app to use multiple databases. One is fixed containing Users and Projects. If I need to create a new project then I want a template based database to be created (Users are in common). So I might have 1,2,3 or more projects databases everyone with the same table config.

I see that in Flask I can assign multiple databases (with a default one):

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')

SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'my_sql1': 'mysql://root:password@localhost/quickhowto'
    'my_sql2': 'mysql://root:password@externalserver.domain.com/quickhowto2'
}
```

Now my problem would be to have the BINDS dynamically added when I want to add a project db to my app.

```
'project1': 'sqlite:///project01.db'
'project2': 'sqlite:///project02.db'
```

So when the user login it chooses a project and then I can select the binds in config.py from storing its initial selection.

But can I modify dynamically the config.py file?